# Understanding when -ing is a gerund or an adjective

Tags: gerunds, parts-of-speech, participial-adjectives

> A possible first step **in developing** a nonsexist vocabulary with which to analyze the works of the nineteenth-century writer Elizabeth Gaskell would be to stop referring to her as “Mrs. Gaskell.”

How does one pin point that the "in developing" used here is not a gerund. Any guidelines to locating an adjective phrase?

Comment: If **developing** were an adjective, it would've modified some noun phrase.  Example: "The developing world" (the adjective modifies the noun **world**). What noun phrase could **developing** modify in your sentence?

Comment: Moreover, *developing* is the object of a preposition, *in*. It is the PP which modifies *step*, not *developing*.

Comment: @StoneyB : I think I am missing something in your explanation.  Which PP modifies *step*?  And what is PP here?  Present Participle? Prepositional Phrase?

Comment: @VictorBazarov Sorry - PP is preposition phrase: *in developing &c* modifies *step*

Comment: I, perhaps erroneously, still conclude that '*developing*' is a gerund...  And I don't see any reasonable clarification in blade's answer.

Answer (score 2):

"in developing a nonsexist vocabulary" is shortened from "in the developing of a nonsexist vocabulary" where you can  clearly see that "developing" has noun character.

By dropping "the" and "of" you get the curious phenomenon that a verb form with noun character can have an object like a verb. i.e. "developing" has noun character and verb character at the same time. For this curious phenomenon we have
the special term gerund.

Answer (score 1):

Nouns can be the subject or object of a sentence/clause/phrase, including *Prepositional Phrases* which is what @StoneyB meant above.

Adjectives modify nouns, but cannot be any of the above.

Note that adjectives can be a [subject complement](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subjectcomplement.htm) if they follow the verbs *be, appear, feel, grow, look, prove, remain, smell, sound, taste,* or *turn* - which looks a lot like an "object" but they are not objects in these cases.

Note also that in English an entire phrase can be an adjective or noun - the phrase itself may have objects, though, but only "within" the phrase.